# Doom Emacs does not correctly render the colors on ssh terminal

Tags: terminal-emacs, doom, ssh

#### What happened?

This is a problem that I was never able to solve and I
always try to switch on another editor when I am coding on my remote machine.

However, I think that I solution should be somewhere for this kind of problem
and that I am the only one that is finding this problem.

MY doom configuration with emacs 29.1 on my host machine

[image]

but the same configuration on the same file in a ssh session shows the following error

[image]

#### What did you expect to happen?

I think the two configurations should be shown the same. I also try to use `export TERM='xterm-256color'` or `export TERM='xterm'` but this do not work for me.

I was also thinking of using TRAMP but this is not working very well for me.

Comment: Does this happen when using `emacs` instead of `emacsclient`?  If so, please remove your [emacsclient] tag.

Comment: I do not understand what the "error" you mentioned is, can you explain ? Also in the bottom image, i.e. on the remote machine, `clangd` appears not to be installed, make sure it is properly installed. Do you use `tree-sitter` ?

Comment: @TristanRiehs the same configuration has different colors on ssh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I discussed the problem on the emacs mailing list [1]

The problem was that my theme assumes 24-bit color, and
my remote machine is not advertising that capability. So I followed the emacs docs
https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Colors-on-a-TTY.html
and ran the following commands to solve my problem

```
$ cat terminfo-custom.src

xterm-emacs|xterm with 24-bit direct color mode for Emacs,
  use=xterm-256color,
  setb24=\E[48\:2\:\:%p1%{65536}%/%d\:%p1%{256}%/%{255}%&\
     %d\:%p1%{255}%&%dm,
  setf24=\E[38\:2\:\:%p1%{65536}%/%d\:%p1%{256}%/%{255}%&\
     %d\:%p1%{255}%&%dm,

$ tic -x -o ~/.terminfo terminfo-custom.src
```

[1] https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2023-10/msg00021.html